# How to set hotkey? - ChromeDriver. Java.

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Can I set hotkey for activate my extension with chromedriver?

Or where does the vm chrome holding it's profile file in windows 10 IntellJ IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the virtual browser stores its profile, set the hotkeys and use this profile for subsequent runs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, for example like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=" + ext_folder);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("chrome://extensions-frame/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='extension-commands-config']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='command-shortcut-text']")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "m");
driver.findElement(By.id("extension-commands-dismiss")).click();

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "m");
```